# Bootup into white abyss after loading screen

Tags: updates, white-screen

my machine started acting up last night. there was an update at some point which may or may not have something to do with it...

I tried to open settings & was met with a glitched panel. mainly white with a little colour if I remember correctly. diagonal lines reminiscent of fractured glass...

I rebooted in an attempt to fix the problem. the machine instead defied me. booted up into the white abyss after the loading screen. also some colour & diagonal lines when interacted with, but not to the extent as the aforementioned settings panel...

(currently running Ubuntu 23.04. booting with 6.2.0.27-generic & 6.2.0.26-generic kernels manifests the white abyss. can boot with 5.15.0-75 but with limited features: unable to connect to internet, no night light, etc)

there is no white abyss in recovery mode. I am able to access the internet & send this message from a browser. however I can hear the abyss calling...

I've tried boot repair, updating, upgrading, reinstalling drives, etc, to no avail. does anyone know what's going on?

(made an attempt at updating to a later kernel. booting into insecure mode however means I cannot boot into recovery mode. the white abyss again manifests. therefore I can't update the kernel...)

[edit- white screen now sometimes includes many colours]

[edit 2 - booting up with removable media shows graphics devices are functional]